# Simple Injector LifetimeScope with DbContext

Tags: signalr, simple-injector

I am using simpleInjector 2.8.0.0 I would like to construct just one instance of a dbContext during a lifetime scope.
(My dependency chain has 2 dependencies on IDatabaseContext/DbContext)

I have a scope decorator which implements the lifetime scope (The scope decorator is being injected into a SignalRHub):

```
  using (ServiceHost.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var commandHandler = ServiceHost.Container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
       //constructs 2 DbContexts.
            commandHandler.Handle(command);
        }
```

I have a lifetime scope registration for the IDatabaseContext:

```
        container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>();
```

However, I can see (from a Guid) that I am creating 2 instances of the IDatabaseContext/DbContext within the scope.

Comment: thanks steven. You are correct I think it was 2 signalr requests.  do you want to add it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is the same scope? Either you are nesting scopes, or you what you see is two actual request being handled. In the debugger, you might be able to view request information, for instance by inspecting the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` property.